# Save list in cell of dataframe to csv

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe like this:

```
-------------------------
| |name|          things| 
-------------------------
|1|John|['car', 'wheel']|
-------------------------
```

When i cal `models.to_csv('models.csv')` I am getting `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'to_csv'`. Can someone help me, how to save list in dataframe cell to csv ?

Comment: Looks like you are trying to save the List variable instead of dataframe. Can you add your code on how do you save the list in dataframe.

Comment: A df like this and with your code works fine by my end

Comment: Check type data `type(models)` I think you have `list` but not `pandas.core.frame.DataFrame`